# Force classifer to select a fixed number of targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

If I have a dataset with events where each event has data with 1000 possible items with only 100 being correct for each event. How do I force my classifier to select only 100 for each event?

After I run it through my training model (with 18 features and always has 100 targets/event flagged as 1) the classifier selects anywhere between 60-80 items instead of 100. Even if I give each event an event number that doesn't help.

I'm using python sklearn gradient boosting and random forest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it yourself. Each classifier in scikit-learn gives you access to decision_function or predict_proba, both of which are support for predict operation (predict is just argmax of these). Thus - just select 100 with the highest support.

Comment: It is giving me lower than 100, is there a way to increase it?

Comment: there is no such thing as "giving lower than". It (using `decision_function` or `predict_proba`) gives you **continuous** response for each class. Just select 100 with the highest. There are always 100 biggest ones (as well as 200, 500 or 1000).

Comment: Got it - i was thinking combination of predict and decision_fuction, thanks - appreciate it !!